# How to turn off automatic Microsoft office updates in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office

I'm using Windows 8. I dont want to turn off all Windows updates. Only ones related to microsoft office. (I have office XP version).

Thanks,

Trinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit to much text to type here IMHO. It's well described at this [location](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/windows-update-settings-windows-8.htm)

Open the Windows 8 Control Panel.

The simplest way to get to Control Panel is probably from its shortcut on the Apps screen but the Power User Menu is great way too if you have a keyboard or mouse.

- Click or tap on the System and Security link.

Note: If you're on the Large icons or Small icons view of Control Panel in Windows 8, choose the Windows Update applet and then skip to Step 4.

- In the System and Security window, click or tap on the Windows Update
  link.
- With Windows Update now open, click or tap the Change settings link
  to the left
- This will open a window with a Choose your Windows Update settings
  heading.

While there are several options here, most people either: a) want updates to install completely automatically, or b) don't ever want an update to download or install by itself.

- Once you've made your choice, click or tap the OK button to confirm
  the changes.

Comment: It may be a bit much but can you at least provide a summary, what if the link goes down? Also from what i can tell it only talks about changing the overall settings, can you copy the part where it talks about only updating windows and not other Microsoft products?

Comment: "can you copy the part where it talks about only updating windows and not other Microsoft products" - This is the important bit, i.e. unchecking "Give me updates for Microsoft products and check for new optional Microsoft software..."

Comment: @Karan I know that is true for XP to 7 but the page did not mention that option for 8. I do not have 8 so I did not know if that option was removed from windows update (perhaps turned on by default).

Comment: I think you need to update Windows Update itself and add Microsoft Update to it using [the following link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r13gs.png) before that option appears under *Change settings*.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to specifically turn off updates for Microsoft Office 2003, you can do this:-

> -Press win+R
>
> -This will open the 'Run' dialog box
>
> -Now open '**services.msc**'
>
> -This should give you a list of running services. Search for '**Office Source Engine**'
>
> -Right Click -> Properties
>
> -Set the **Startup Type** -> "**Disabled**"

This will not start the updater for Microsoft Office.
Hope this helps.